# Kendo Grid paging not working properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo MVC grid. Using data table instead of Model to display in grid. and populating the data based on page no. but paging is not working below is my code:

List.cshtml file

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("UserGrid")
.EnableCustomBinding(true)
.Columns(columns=>
  { 
      foreach(System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
      {
          columns.Bound(column.ColumnName).Title(column.Caption).Width(200);
      }
   }
)
.Selectable(selectable=>selectable
   .Type(GridSelectionType.Row)
)
.Pageable()
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
         {
             foreach(System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
             { 
                 model.Field(column.ColumnName,column.DataType);
             }
         }
     )
      .Total((int)ViewData["recordcount"])
     .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "User").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
 )
 )
```

Here is the Controller code. UserList function will return the data as datatable and Read function to populate the data and pass it through grid:

```
  private DataTable UserList()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        if (ViewData["pageno"] != null && Convert.ToInt16(ViewData["pageno"]) > 1)
        {
            iUserSearch.pageNumber = Convert.ToInt16(ViewData["pageno"]);
        }
        else
        {
            iUserSearch.pageNumber = 1;
        }
        iUserSearch.pageSize = 10;
        ds = iUser.ListUser(iUserSearch);
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable = ds.Tables[0];
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0 )
            ViewData["recordcount"] = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Totalcount"];
        return dataTable;

    }


    public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        //Paging and Sorting
        int currentPage = request.Page;
        int pageSize = request.PageSize;

        ViewData["pageno"] = currentPage;
        //Setting the TOTAL
        DataTable dt = UserList();
        //return View("List",dt);
        //var result = dt;
        return Json(dt.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean paging is not working? What happens?

Comment: when click the next page. data is not getting load. while debugging Model is showing the updated data. seems not getting rendered..

Comment: Are you using a custom Kendo javascript file? If yes, make sure you have chosen paging as part of the grid functionality.

Comment: Yes i am using js file. If i remove kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js in layout file, its working fine. But need this js for Filter and other feature in grid

Comment: of course you are using a `.js` file. My question was are you using a custom `.js` file (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom) or `kendo.all.min.js`?

Comment: not the custom script. using kendo.all.min.js

Comment: Make sure you put `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` after `kendo.all.min.js`.

Comment: yes I included kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js as last scrip. still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by assigning model id in view